# ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, urlencode

```
try:
    from urllib import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    
import speech_recognition
```

when I run `import speech_recognition` normally it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from urllib import urlencode
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\New folder\virtual ai assistant.py", line 2, in <module>
        import speech_recognition as sr
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
        import http.client
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
        from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
        from email._policybase import compat32
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
        from email.utils import _has_surrogates
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
        from email._parseaddr import quote
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
        import time, calendar
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\calendar.py", line 50, in <module>
        class _localized_month:
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in _localized_month
        _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
      File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
        _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
    AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
    [Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
    [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\New folder\virtual ai assistant.py"]
    [dir: C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\New folder]
    [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Android;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Vatsa\.dotnet\tools]
```

so I checked about this and changed the code as it is at the very top but when I run that I still receive the same error.

Comment: What's your `speech_recognition` version?

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: `pip show speech_recognition` in cmd prompt

Comment: Name: SpeechRecognition
Version: 3.8.1

Comment: Full error traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from urllib import urlencode
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: "another exception occurred" what's below that? Also, please edit details into the question itself.

Comment: the other trace back message is too long to fit in here ill add it in the question

Comment: `from urllib.parse import urlencode` try edit `init.py`

Comment: @Neizvestnyj Its a 3rd-party library, don't edit its source unless its actually necessary.\

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: Do you have a file named `datetime.py` or a folder named `datetime` anywhere?

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: @SuperStormer I agree with you, just the import is not correct

Comment: ohh if you are importing as `import datetime` then its `datetime.datetime.date`

Comment: oh wow! i feel so dumb right now i did have a file named datetime.py im sorry for wasting your time thank you so much

Comment: @Neizvestnyj nope, the import is correct - its erroring for a different reason

Comment: the code works now the only reason that error was coming was because i had a file named datetime.py, thankyou guys

Answer (score 1):

Reposting from my comment:

You have a file named `datetime.py` that's being imported instead of stdlib `datetime`, just rename the file to something different.